# Как удалить ветку develop и установить другую ветку вместо нее?

Tags: git, source-tree

Можно ли удалить ветку develop и установить другую ветку вместо нее? Если да то как?

Comment: Расскажите лучше, для чего вам это нужно? Цель какая?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего Вас просто нужно просто переименовать ветку.

Можно ли сделать это в source tree - я не знаю, но это точно можно сделать в обычной консоле.  Открываете консоль и пишете

```
git branch -m develop новая_ветка
```

если же "новая_ветка" уже существует, то либо ее вначале нужно удалить, либо просто написать большую M

```
git branch -M develop новая_ветка
```

В git коммиты не знают о том, к какой ветки они пренадлежат, поэтому, если просто переименовать ветку, то коммиты об этом не узнают.

Но ещё остается одна вещь - ветки в удаленном репозитории. И тут можно просто забывать о ветке develop на сервере (ее могут пользоваться и другие пользователи). Поэтому, для начала нужно ветку отправить на удаленный сервер - `git push -u origin новая_ветка`, а саму ветку develop удалить на сервере.

Я знаю, что некоторые здесь очень сильно любят source tree и даже минусуют меня за критику этой программы, но все равно не рекомендую им пользоваться.

P.S. - если все таки хочется делать это в source tree - попробуйте кликнуть правой кнопкой по имени ветки и поискать там "переименовать".

Comment: У нее будут функции develop'a ?

Comment: А что такое функции develop'a?

Comment: Можно будет создавать подветки

Comment: ветки можно создавать от любой ветки и от любого коммита. Так как имя ветки это просто псевдоним  коммита, то от переименования ветки, функциональность ветки не меняется. Ну кроме имени.

Comment: Плюс за критику SourceTree )

Comment: Второй плюс за критику SourceTree )

Answer (score 0):

Удаляет локальную ветку, если уже сделан её пуш и мердж:

git branch -d branch_name

Принудительно (force) удаляет локальную ветку, несмотря ни на что:

git branch -D branch_name

Теперь удалим такую же ветку из самого репозитория:

git push origin --delete stage